# How to edit media messages on aiogram 3

Tags: aiogram

How to display several photos and descriptions in one message so that they change after clicking on the inline button in the same message

```py
@catalog_router.callback_query(lambda c: c.data.startswith('cookies'))
async def cookies(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    photo = FSInputFile('./data/assets/cookies.jpg')
    await call.message.answer_photo(photo,
        caption=
        """
        Привіт друзі YUMMYK на зв'язку) Сьогодні, ми попрацювали на славу! І готували надзвичайно смачне печиво, як з дитинства. Бо кожному батьки купляли саме "вівсяне печиво" кажучи, що воно корисне. Наша команда вирішила, що ми також будемо готувати корисне печиво. Процес приготування цього рецепту нас просто заворожив, і в результаті отримали печиво, яке точно заслуговує вашої уваги!
        """, 
        reply_markup = conditers_catalog
    )
```

It's just an output message, but it doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

To create a group of photo/videos, you can use [MediaGroupBuilder](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/media_group.html).

To edit media content of a message, you can use [editMessageMedia](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/methods/edit_message_media.html#editmessagemedia) method. Read the description there, editing grouped media has limitations.

To edit the caption of the Media group message, use [editMessageCaption](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/methods/edit_message_caption.html) method.

To help distinguish types of the message content, you can check `call.message.content_type` and compare it to the aiogram's enum [ContentType](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/enums/content_type.html).

A really quick example:

```py
from aiogram.types import ContentType, FSInputFile

if (call.message.content_type == ContentType.TEXT):
    await bot.edit_message_text( 
        text='New message text',
        chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
        message_id=call.message.message_id,
        reply_markup=conditers_catalog)

elif (call.message.content_type == ContentType.PHOTO):
    await bot.edit_message_media(
        chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
        message_id=call.message.message_id,
        media=FSInputFile('./data/assets/cookies.jpg',filename='cookies.jpg'),
        reply_markup=conditers_catalog)

    await bot.edit_message_caption(
        caption='New caption text',
        chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
        message_id=call.message.message_id,
        reply_markup=conditers_catalog)
```